# optimise django sql query

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm using **Django 2.x**.

I have two models

```
class AmountGiven(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.FloatField(help_text='Amount given to the contact')
    interest_rate = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    given_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    total_due = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0.0, editable=False)

class AmountReturned(models.Model):
    amount_given = models.ForeignKey(AmountGiven, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    return_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
```

**Use case**

- There can be multiple records of the amount given to a contact
- There can be multiple records of the returned amount for an amount given

**Now, I want to get `total_due` amount for a particular contact.** This includes

```
total_payable = total_given + interest 
total_due = total_payable - total_returned
```

To calculate `total_due` and `interest`, I have defined few **property** methods in the **AmountGiven** model.

```
@property
def interest_to_pay(self):
    if self.interest_rate:
        simple_interest_amount = ...
        return simple_interest_amount

    return 0

@property
def total_payable(self):
    return self.amount + self.interest_to_pay

@property
def amount_due(self):
    total_due = self.total_payable - self.total_returned

    self.total_due = total_due
    self.save()

    return total_due

@property
def total_returned(self):
    returned_amount = self.amountreturned_set.aggregate(total_returned=Sum('amount'))['total_returned']
    if not returned_amount:
        returned_amount = 0

    return returned_amount
```

In **Contact** model, there is a **property** method to get the total due amount for the contact.

```
@property
def amount_due(self):
    total_due = 0
    for due in self.amountgiven_set.all():
        total_due += due.amount_due

    return total_due
```

**Query**

**ContactSerializer**

```
class ContactMinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = (
            'id', 'first_name', 'amount_due', 'created', 'modified'
        )
```

Since `amount_due` property is being used in the `ContactSerializer`, `amount_due` property is called everytime a contact is call and thus results in nested DB queries.

How can I optimise the above scenario in the application to reduce the DB queries while getting contact or list of contacts? Specially two properties **amount_due** and **total_returned**.

**amount_due()** updates the **total_due** field in the table, every time it is called.

> Edit 2

```
class ContactViewSet(LoggingMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactMinSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Contact.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(
            total_due=Sum(
                F('amountgiven_set__total_payable')
                - F('amountgiven_set__total_returned')
            )
        ).order_by('first_name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You're looking for annotations.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)

Your viewset should define a queryset as follows:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum
Contact.objects.annotate(
    total_due=Sum(
        F('amountgiven_set__total_payable')
        - F('amountgiven_set__total_returned')
    )
)
```

Then define a MethodSerializer field on your serializer to account for it.

```
class ContactMinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_due = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_due(self, obj):
        return return self.total_due

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = (
            'id', 'first_name', 'created', 'modified',
            'total_due',
        )
```

Comment: For every `n` requests, `@property total_returned()` is running for `n` times which is resulting in further `n` db queries. This becomes worst when n is high. I want to reduce query fetch for `total_returned` because  calculation of `amount_due` is dependent on `total_returned` and interest calculation. Is there a way to get `total_returned` in single query? Currently in my case it is running 100+ queries which is worst.

Comment: Correct. You can do more annotations than just what I did above. You should be able to apply the logic from above to your other properties.

Comment: check `Edit 2`. In case of adding to serializer, it gives error as `Cannot resolve keyword 'amountgiven_set' into field.`

Comment: Look into the `related_name` property on your field.